# Is there a generic attack on encrypted CRC32 when used as a MAC?

Tags: encryption, authentication, mac, attack, crc

I am examining a protocol that uses CRC32 as a MAC (see note 1) the weaknesses of this method but I would nevertheless like to see if it is just weak or actually relatively easily to break.

The examined protocol has the format more or less of:

```
Plaintext = Headers (6 bytes) || CRC (4 bytes) || Data
Ciphertext = 3DES-CBC(Plaintext)
```

This is used for a Server to send a Client a message and the Client will authenticate the message by decrypting it and checking the CRC. An attacker cannot ask the Server or the Client to encrypt a message, they could predict though the plaintext from a ciphertext.

Searching about it I can see that there is [an attack on SSH 1.5](http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=advisory&name=_SSH_insertion_attack) that is similar. To perform the attack the format of the data is put into this format for SSH:

```
Plaintext = Padding (8 bytes) || Data || CRC (4 bytes)
Ciphertext = 3DES-CBC(Plaintext)
```

The attack is performed partially by taking advantage of the CBC encryption by changing the first block which is the 8 byte padding in order to manipulate the second 8 byte block. If I was to perform the same attack though on the examined protocol since the 4 byte CRC is split between the first and second protocol it wouldn't work.

Note that the question is not if the protocol is weaker compared to a protocol where a proper MAC like HMAC had been used but if there is any attack that could relatively easily break the authentication.

**NOTES**

1. From fgrieu: The terminology is not quite right: CRC32 can't be used as (a weak substitute for) a MAC, for it is a keyless transformation of the message. Rather, here, it is used as (a weak substitute for) a hash in a hash-then-encrypt scheme

Comment: CRC is not a MAC at all, it provides no authentication

Comment: The terminology is not quite right: CRC32 can't be used as (a weak substitute for) a MAC, for it is a keyless transformation of the message. Rather, here, it is used as (a weak substitute for) a hash in a hash-then-encrypt scheme, something [which itself does not generally insure message integrity](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/16431/555). $\;$ If the IV for the 3DES-CBC encryption is 8 random bytes prepended to the cryptogram, and the length of Data variable, and the adversary able to mount a chosen-ciphertext attacks, then such generic attacks on hash-then-CBC-encrypt work here.

Comment: @fgrieu : $\:$ Is there such an attack when the hash goes _before_ the plaintext? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: Yes. Adapted to the present context (with CRC instead of Hash, but that works for a hash just the same): one decides the desired Forgery, computes its CRC, builds 6zeroes||Headers||CRC||Forgery, submits that as (chosen) Data for authentication and encryption; and from the resulting cryptogram removes the first 16 bytes (including 8 bytes IV). What remains will pass verification (the first 8 bytes will be the IV).

Comment: In my first comment, read "_the adversary able to mount a chosen-**PLAINTEXT** attack_".

Answer (score 3):

Well, 32 bits is somewhat short, so one could just try ciphertexts.

However, there is a much better attack.

Choose `M0` arbitrarily, let `P` be the CBC [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) for `Headers || CRC || M0`,

and choose `M1` so that `CRC( M0 || P || M1 )  =  CRC(M0)`.

Submit `M0 || P || M1` to be encrypted, truncate the ciphertext to the length of

encryptions of `M0`, and then output the result. $\:$ That will be a valid encryption of `M0`.

Even without chosen plaintext, one should be able to change the headers.

Let `H` be the headers and let `CL` be the first 16 bits of `CRC` and let  `L` be the (bit-)length of `Data`.

Choose 48 bits `X` which are not all zero so that the CRC of [`X` combined with `L` zero bits

however the protocol does that] ends with the same 16 bits as the CRC of `48+L` zero bits.

Xor the IV with [`X` concatenated with [the xor of the first 16 bits of the two just-mentioned CRCs.

By the [affineness of CRC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/704/991), the result will be a valid ciphertext

with the same `Data` and header `H xor X`.

Comment: I should have added that the protocol doesn't support asking for a specific plaintext to be encrypted. So basically the server will send a message to the client and the client will authenticate it using this protocol. The plaintext could be predicted though.

Comment: How long is the message? $\;$

Comment: Th message could be as small as 16 bytes and as big probably to a couple of hundrend bytes

Comment: What [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) do they use? $\:$ How many possible plaintexts are there? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @Antikithira : $\:$ Also, is the CRC computers over `Headers` too or just `Data`? $\hspace{1.62 in}$

Comment: The CRC computes over headers as well. The padding would be a PKCS#5. There wouldn't be a lot of plaintexts, maybe up to ten.

Comment: @Antikithira : $\:$ Do the outputs distinguish between invalid padding and invalid CRC? $\hspace{1.3 in}$

Comment: Also, since the CRC computes over headers as well, "plaintexts" from four comments ago should be interpreted as "header/data pairs". $\;$

Comment: you mean if it would make a difference if the padding is invalid or CRC? They would both fail with different failure code, so you could distinguish between the two